# Extracting Several Files contents Within a folder into one file with Visual Basic and userform to chose the folder

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a macro in Visual Basic that will select all  of the Excel files from a folder and put them into a single file. I used a form with a button that will open a window to select the folders.

Here's the button code, here I can only choose the file instead of the folders:

```
Private Sub importer_Click()
    Dim file As String
    file = Application.GetOpenFilename("excel (*.xlsx),*.xlsx", , "Chose", , True)

    If (LCase(file) <> "Faux" And file <> "0") Then

        liste_elements.AddItem (file)

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's your actual question / problem?

Answer (score 0):

In order to select more than one file you should set the MultiSelect parameter to true.

Read more about it here: [Application.GetOpenFilename Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-getopenfilename-method-excel)

Comment: First of all thank you for you answer,
yes i know with that method i can select multiple files but i want to select a folder then the program will extract all the files inside the folder into one file.